# Making a rubbing screen gesture in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

Basically, I want to make a mobile game using a custom hand gesture. The gesture is kind of like rubbing the screen, from left to right and from right to left.

If the gesture moves from the left to right, this will call a method and add a point. And once the gesture rubs from right to left, the user can also get one point.

But the problem is, when I use Swipe gesture recognizer, I have to release my finger from the screen, in order to call the method. If I just do the rub gesture, I am unable to call the method to add points.

Instead, I try the touchesBegan, touchesMoved method to detect the finger's position. However, touchesMoved will create many points to compare with the starting point, which leads to calling the methods many times instead of once.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        self.touchStartPoint = touch.locationInView(self.myView).x
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        self.touchOffsetPoint = touch.locationInView(self.myView).x - touchStartPoint

        if tempTouchOffsetPoint < touchOffsetPoint
        {
            var xValueIncreaseArray: NSMutableArray = []
            xValueIncreaseArray.addObject(touchOffsetPoint)
            var maxValue: Double = (xValueIncreaseArray as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("@max.self") as Double

            println("\(maxValue)")

            if maxValue - Double (self.touchStartPoint) > 50
            {
                println("right")
            }

            println("right")
        }
        else if tempTouchOffsetPoint > touchOffsetPoint
        {
           /* var xValueDecreaseArray: NSMutableArray = []
            xValueDecreaseArray.addObject(touchOffsetPoint)*/
            println("left")
        }
        else if tempTouchOffsetPoint == touchOffsetPoint
        {
            println("Remain")
        }
        tempTouchOffsetPoint = touchOffsetPoint
    }
```

Are there any ways to detect the rubbing gesture? And every time the finger turns its direction, it will call a method only ONCE to add a score to user? Thank you so much!

Comment: I believe you are looking for a UIPanGestureRecognizer, which will give you a new update whenever the finger moves (however, you will have to calculate the direction).

Comment: I am afraid that UIPanGestureRecognizer can not be called ONLY ONCE. I tried and it will be called many times.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
let deadZone:CGFloat = 10.0
var previousTouchPoint: CGFloat!
var isMovingLeft:Bool? = nil

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let point = touches.anyObject()?.locationInView(self)

    if let newPoint = point?.x {

        if previousTouchPoint == nil {
            println("Started")
            previousTouchPoint = newPoint
        } else {

            // Check if they have moved beyond the dead zone
            if (newPoint < (previousTouchPoint - deadZone)) || (newPoint > (previousTouchPoint + deadZone)) {

                let newDirectionIsLeft = newPoint < previousTouchPoint

                // Check if the direction has changed
                if isMovingLeft != nil && newDirectionIsLeft != isMovingLeft! {
                    println("Direction Changed: Point")
                }

                println((newDirectionIsLeft) ? "Moving Left" : "Moving Right")

                isMovingLeft = newDirectionIsLeft
                previousTouchPoint = newPoint
            }

        }

    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    previousTouchPoint = nil
    isMovingLeft = nil
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    previousTouchPoint = nil
    isMovingLeft = nil
}
```